# If an Object at Rest has zero net force, why does it have gravitational potential energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy, inertial-frames

Also, if I throw an eraser on a table shouldn't it's g.p.e be $mg$ times its height from the ground, plus the additional height on the table instead of just the height on the table?

Answer (score 4):

The object by itself does not have gravitational potential energy.
The object and Earth system has gravitational potential energy.
When the object is moved further from the Earth then the object and Earth system has more gravitational energy than before.
If the object is on the surface of the Earth and goes down a well then the object and Earth system has less gravitational potential energy than before.

Comment: So if an object is placed on a table and I lift it by lets say 2m from the table would its g.p.e be mg*2 or would it be mg*(2+height of table from the ground)?

Comment: It would be a **difference** in the potential energy of $mg\Delta h$ with the potential energy being higher when the object is further from the Earth.  You are allowed to make the potential energy at the Earth's surface be zero and then the potential energy at a height $\Delta h$ above the Earth's surface is $mg \Delta h$.